# Как сделать активной иконку Папки на боковой панели VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

При открытии проекта в редакторе VSCode , что бы увидеть дерево папок, приходится руками кликать иконку "Папки". По умолчанию она не активна. Как вернуть ее активность по открытию проекта в редакторе ?
[вид боковой панели при открытии папки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kksJV.png)

Comment: Насколько я помню - никак. Но если вы открываете "папку проекта", то там настройки эти сохраняются.